# Watchkit app extension not launching

Tags: ios, watchkit

My watchkit app extension has suddenly stopped launching. I have a breakpoint in `(void)awakeWithContext:(id)context`, but that does not get called.

I am running the WatchKit app extension, and all the certificates are in order. I have a 42mm screen set as the external hardware display. I have tried re-starting XCode.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had during the course of development cleared my `DerviedData`. This removes the WatchKit extension from the list of embedded binaries in the app. To fix this, you have to 
1. Rebuild the project.
2. Click on Add Embedded Binaries, select the "App Name WatchKit extension.appex" file.

This solved the problem for me.